# Sysbench insert data between a given range

Tags: mysql, mariadb, benchmark

I was trying to insert 1,000,000 records of data into 1,000 tables in sysbench. But after installing about 278, sybench just crashed with the following error:

> FATAL: failed to execute function `prepare': /usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/common.lua:84: db_bulk_insert_next() failed

The sysbench command I used for preparing the data is given below:

```
sysbench --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --mysql-table-engine=innodb --oltp-tables-count=1000 --oltp-table-size=100000 --mysql-user=superuser --mysql-password=superpass --mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock prepare
```

I do not want to start preparing the data from scratch again. Is there a way I can declare a range on which to insert data e.g. `oltp-tables-count=279-1000`. I know this does not work because I tried already, but you get the idea what I am trying to achieve here. Any ideas how to accomplish this in sysbench?